# Where does the "resize" handle in browser textboxes come from?

Tags: firefox, browser, html, css

Where does the resize handle on browser textboxes come from? Is it a browser* implementation, or an HTML/CSS/JavaScript/etc. implementation?

[image: Resize handle]

Is it standardized across browsers/operating systems/frameworks/protocols/etc. in any way?

I notice that it's sometimes missing from textboxes -- like Superuser's question textbox -- which leads me to believe there's some sort of HTML/CSS interaction factoring into play.

But maybe not.

*(For reference, I'm using Firefox v22 on Windows 7 x64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a css programming part of the page and by default allow the resize on both horizontally and vertically.
 To disable them all in a site you add this on the css of the page:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: Much obliged. What do you mean by "open"? An open standard?

Comment: @Coldblackice The word "open" is not the correct. By default is  `resize:both` meaning that allow to resize the text area.

Answer (score 0):

It is a part of CSS3 (CSS version 3). The resize property is supported in Firefox 4+, Chrome, and Safari.
You can read more about the resize property here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp and all other CSS property.

Comment: The official standard is CSS Basic User Interface Module Level 3 (CSS3 UI) which is currently in working draft. Here is the relevant section: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize

Comment: Based he's question, I would not ask him to read w3.org definitions. Therefore, I believe that w3schools.com is the best offer. _(w3schools.com offer try it, overview of browser support property, overview and explanation of the property and more. (You can compare w3 with w3s to see if there is some mistakes)_